# How do I raise X to the power of Y in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, math, exponent, exponentiation

I (apparently wrongly) assumed there would be a built-in power `operator` or `function` in Powershell, but I it seems there is not, or is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer:

```
[Math]::Pow(256,3) # 256 to the power of 3 (= ~16.7 million)
```

Answer (score 18):

As you've found, real exponentation can be achieved with some accuracy by calling [`[Math]::Pow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow).

For large integer exponentiation, you might want to use [`[bigint]::Pow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.pow) instead:

```
PS ~> [Math]::Pow(256, 20)
1.4615016373309E+48
PS ~> [bigint]::Pow(256, 20)
1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976
```